# VB.NET Object with custom name to store property?

Tags: vb.net

I'm not familiar with the type of structure or whatever I need to use to achieve this, but I know that there is one.

I'm trying to make it so that I can reference things something like this:

`racerlist(x).compatibilityArr.john.CleatScore`

instead of what I have to do now:

`racerlist(x).compatibilityArr.CleatScoreArr(y).name/.score`

So essentially, I want to add items to the compatibilityarr (will probably have to change to a list which is fine) and be able to reference the racer as their own name, instead of by using an index.

Comment: Maybe use a Dictionary or create an extention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Codexer mentioned, I used a dictionary to achieve this.

In my list of Racers (RacerList), I have RacerCompatibility, which I created similar to below:

```
Public RacerCompatibility As New Dictionary(Of String, Compatibility)
```

Compatibility is created like:

```
Public Class Compatibility
    Public Cleat As Boolean
    Public Skill As Integer
    Public Height As Integer
End Class
```

So now I can access the compatibility of a racer inside the list like:

RacerList(x).RacerCompatibility.Item("John")

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to build a solution that fits your needs as described above. It requires an embedded class that is built as a `List(Of T)` where we overload the property to accept a string rather than the integer.

```
Public Class Foo
  Public Property compatibilityArr As New Members
End Class

Public Class Members : Inherits List(Of Member)
Public Overloads ReadOnly Property Item(name As String) As Member
 Get
  Return Me.Where(Function(i) i.Name = name).FirstOrDefault
 End Get
End Property
End Class

Public Class Member
 Public Property Name As String
 Public Property CleatScore As Integer
End Class
```

Then to use it:

```
Public Class Form1
  Dim f As New Foo
  Private Sub loads() Handles Me.Load
    Dim member As New Member With {.Name = "John", .CleatScore = 10}
    f.compatibilityArr.Add(member)
    MessageBox.Show(f.compatibilityArr.Item("John").CleatScore)
  End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways to do this, but the simplest is to write a function to search the array by name:

```
  Sub Main1()
    Dim racerlist(2) As Racer
    racerlist(0) = New Racer With {.Name = "Adam", .CleatScore = "1"}
    racerlist(1) = New Racer With {.Name = "Bill", .CleatScore = "2"}
    racerlist(2) = New Racer With {.Name = "Charlie", .CleatScore = "3"}
    For i As Integer = 0 To racerlist.GetUpperBound(0)
      For j As Integer = 0 To racerlist.GetUpperBound(0)
        If racerlist(j).Name <> racerlist(i).Name Then
          ReDim Preserve racerlist(i).CompatibilityArr(racerlist(i).CompatibilityArr.GetUpperBound(0) + 1)
          racerlist(i).CompatibilityArr(racerlist(i).CompatibilityArr.GetUpperBound(0)) = racerlist(j)
        End If
      Next j
    Next i
    Dim racerBill As Racer = Racer.FindRacer(racerlist, "Bill")
    MsgBox(racerBill.FindCompatibility("Charlie").CleatScore)
  End Sub

  Class Racer
    Property Name As String
    Property CleatScore As String
    Property CompatibilityArr As Racer()
    Sub New()
      ReDim CompatibilityArr(-1) 'initialise the array
    End Sub
    Function FindCompatibility(name As String) As Racer
      Return FindRacer(CompatibilityArr, name)
    End Function
    Shared Function FindRacer(racerlist() As Racer, name As String) As Racer
      For i As Integer = 0 To racerlist.GetUpperBound(0)
        If racerlist(i).Name = name Then
          Return racerlist(i)
        End If
      Next i
      Return Nothing
    End Function
  End Class
```